# What is '<?dctm xml_app="ignore"?> '?

Tags: html, xml

I have encountered this tag in an xml file :

```
<?dctm xml_app="ignore"?>
```

What does this tag mean / signify ?

Googling this value did not return results as to what it means.

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.google.com/search?q=<%3Fdctm+xml_app%3D"ignore"%3F> I see plenty of results mentioning something called Documentum.

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't realise dctm was an alias for Documentum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<?...?>` syntax is an [XML processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi):

> **Processing instructions** (PIs) allow documents to contain instructions for applications.

In this case it appears to be an instruction for [*Documentum*](http://www.emc.com/domains/documentum/index.htm), a content management system. When the document in question is stored in this application, it can specify some details about how it is to be handled by the application.

If you are not using the application in question you can probably just ignore this instruction, although obviously this will depend on exactly what you are doing with the document.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is [**`Leave my XML file alone in Documentum`**](http://www.ukoom.com/leave-my-xml-file-alone-in-documentum.htm) : *To disable XML validation on import add the processing instruction `<”dctm xml_app=”ignore”">` to the xml file. This will halt the parsing algorithm.*

Comment: What is Documentum ? does this mean this xml file is being parsed by a product created by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentum ?

Answer (score 0):

The value Ignore tells the system not to process this document as an XML 
document. You must include this instruction; if you leave it out, the system 
will use the Default XML Application to process the document.